# Change the structure of local google drive folder

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

If I change the structure of folder inside local Google Drive folder
does the changes be uploaded to the Google Drive online?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using [Backup and Sync](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987#zippy=%2Cwindows) and have chosen a folder on your system to store and synchronize folders and files within your unit (`My Drive`).

By default, all changes you make to your local folder are synchronized with your online drive, i.e. if you move files between folders, or create or delete anything, the change will be reflected. It is a bidirectional behavior, if you want more information about how this system works and how to modify it, visit the link I have provided.